# Адаптивная таблица в столбик

Tags: html, css, таблицы, табличная-верстка

Нужно из левой таблицы сделать правую таблицу. Знаю что таблицы обычно для адаптива ломают по строкам, но мне нужно сломать ее так, чтобы колонки таблицы начали переноситься на новые строки. На скрине нарисовал макет таблиц, чтобы было понятно, с чем у меня проблема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код, код, добавьте ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

Если  есть возможность влезть в код таблицы - надо это сделать и переверстать ее дивами.

Если нет - можно поизвращаться с помощью, например, `flex`:

```css
.GeneratedTable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.GeneratedTable tbody,
.GeneratedTable thead,
.GeneratedTable tr {
  display: contents;
}

.GeneratedTable td,
.GeneratedTable th {
  display: block;
}

.GeneratedTable td:nth-of-type(1),
.GeneratedTable th:nth-of-type(1) {
  order: 1;
}

.GeneratedTable td:nth-of-type(2),
.GeneratedTable th:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 2;
}

.GeneratedTable td:nth-of-type(3),
.GeneratedTable th:nth-of-type(3) {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<table class="GeneratedTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>h1</th>
      <th>h2</th>
      <th>h3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Стили заданы грязно и негибко, и не факт, что везде поддерживаются, но полировать ответ до совершенства мне лень =)

Answer (score 0):

Через js можно создать новые строки таблицы, задать им отдельный класс и сделать их адаптивными:

```js
const tables = document.querySelectorAll('.js-adaptive-table');
tables.forEach((table) => {
  let trs = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  let tds_length = trs[0].children.length;
  let tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');

  while (--tds_length >= 0) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');

    trs.forEach((tds) => {
      tr.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', tds.children[tds_length].cloneNode(true));
    });

    tr.classList.add('adaptive-tr');
    tbody.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', tr);
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

thead td {
  background-color: black;
}

tr {
  display: none;
}

tr.adaptive-tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

tr.adaptive-tr td:first-of-type {
  background-color: black;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  tr.adaptive-tr {
    display: none;
  }
  tr {
    display: table;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="js-adaptive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```